# Student's t as a power law distribution

Tags: extreme-value, t-distribution, pareto-distribution, power-law, heavy-tailed

I'm currently reading about power laws and I have came across an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34924251/how-can-i-find-the-power-law-parameter-of-a-student-t-distribution-in-python) stating:

> The density function of a Student's t-distribution with $n$ degrees of freedom is:
> $$f(x) \sim (1 + x^2 / n)^{-(n+1)/2}.$$
> In the tails (for large absolute values of $x$) this is asymptomatically proportional to:
> $$x^{-(n+1)}.$$
> So the exponent in the power law (your $\alpha$) is $n+1$.

My question is how $x^{-(n+1)}$ was derived?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$\dfrac{(1 + x^2 / n)^{-(n+1)/2}}{x^{-(n+1)}} = \left(\dfrac{1}{x^2} +\dfrac1n \right)^{-(n+1)/2} \to \left(\dfrac1n \right)^{-(n+1)/2}$$ as $x\to \infty$ while $n$ remains fixed, i.e. the limit of the ratio is a positive constant,

so $(1 + x^2 / n)^{-(n+1)/2}$ is asymptomatically proportional  to  $x^{-(n+1)}$ in the right tail.

You can do something similar to say it is asymptomatically proportional  to  $|x|^{-(n+1)}$ in both tails.

Comment: Hi @Henry, thank you for the answer. I have a question regarding the derivation if you don't mind: Why did we divide $(1 + x^2 / n)^{-(n+1)/2}$ by $x^{-(n+1)}$ rather than say $x^{-(2n + 1/n + 1)}$ to check if $(1 + x^2 / n)^{-(n+1)/2}$ is asymptomatically proportional to the latter? How did we stumble upon $x^{-(n+1)}$ in the first place? I apologize for additional question and thanks in advance.

Comment: @BlgKhalil - The active term is $(x^2)^{-(n+1)/2}$ which for $x \ge 0$ is equal to $x^{-(n+1)}$ so it makes sense to concentrate on that

Comment: Very well understood! Thank you so much @Henry.